# WSO2 API : how to create custom api usage statistics in wso2 api manager and analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am fairly new in this tool. I need some guidance and help to create custom api usage statistics in wso2 api manager and analytics.
Right now I am using H2 database which is embedded in wso2 and need to generate report from database which has custom information.
I have been able to extract the data from various usage table like (API_RESOURCE_USAGE_SUMMARY and API_REQUEST_SUMMARY) but not able to include other details in this which is necessary for the use case on which I am working right now.

Guidance in this would be really helpful.